# Why Azure Web app Bot gives wrong answer?

Tags: c#, azure, chatbot, azure-qna-maker, language-studio

i've created a Web app Bot for Q&A on Azure, following those steps:

- created a new project and filled the Q&A knowledge base con [Language Studio](https://language.cognitive.azure.com/)
- Deployed it from language studio
- Created a bot from language studio, as a C# bot
- Added a Direct Line channel to the Web app Bot

When i go to the created resource, and try to test it, i get "almost" twice the same reply from the bot:

[image]

i've tested it also from the Bot Framework Emulator, downloading the source code generated by Azure, and i have the same result.
Obviously it is the same also in the chatbot integrated in an actual webapp.
If the answer is just a simple, single line one, i don't see any problem.
Also, if i try to do the same test in Language Studio i get the correct response.

The answer i expect is actually only the second part.

I noticed that when i test the bot from "Test in Web Chat" in Azure Portal, the request is being done to the endpoint

> https://webchat.botframework.com//v3/directline/conversations/*****/activities

Instead, when i test it from Language Studio, the request looks like this

> https://***********.cognitiveservices.azure.com/language/:query-knowledgebases?projectName=*****&api-version=2021-10-01&deploymentName=test

how can i understand what's goin on here?

EDIT:
i found something very weird: if the question is asked without a question mark the answer is fine

EDIT 2:
i found out it depends on the answer numbered list in markdown!
if i replace the numbered list with a dotted one the reply is just fine, with or without the question mark

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working..

The behaviour i was seeing seems very likely to be a bug, but there is at lease a workaround.

If i go to the related app service configurations, and set **EnablePreciseAnswer** fo **false** everything works fine